# Python 3.6 script surprisingly slow on Windows 10 but not on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

I recently had to write a challenge for a company that was to merge 3 CSV files into one based on the first attribute of each (the attributes were repeating in all files).

I wrote the code and sent it to them, but they said it took 2 minutes to run. That was funny because it ran for 10 seconds on my machine. My machine had the same processor, 16GB of RAM, and had an SSD as well. Very similar environments.

I tried optimising it and resubmitted it. This time they said they ran it on an Ubuntu machine and got 11 seconds, while the code ran for 100 seconds on the Windows 10 still.

Another peculiar thing was that when I tried profiling it with the [Profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-profile) module, it went on forever, had to terminate after 450 seconds. I moved to [cProfiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) and it recorded it for 7 seconds.

EDIT: The exact formulation of the problem is

> Write a console program to merge the files provided in a *timely* and
>   *efficient* manner. File paths should be supplied as arguments so that
>   the program can be evaluated on different data sets. The merged file
>   should be saved as CSV; use the id column as the unique key for
>   merging; the program should do any necessary data cleaning and error
>   checking.
>
> Feel free to use any language you’re comfortable with – only
>   restriction is no external libraries as this defeats the purpose of
>   the test. If the language provides CSV parsing libraries (like
>   Python), please avoid using them as well as this is a part of the
>   test.

Without further ado here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

HEADERS = ['id']

def csv_tuple_quotes_valid(a_tuple):
    """
    checks if a quotes in each attribute of a entry (i.e. a tuple) agree with the csv format

    returns True or False
    """
    for attribute in a_tuple:
        in_quotes = False
        attr_len = len(attribute)
        skip_next = False

        for i in range(0, attr_len):
            if not skip_next and attribute[i] == '\"':
                if i < attr_len - 1 and attribute[i + 1] == '\"':
                    skip_next = True
                    continue
                elif i == 0 or i == attr_len - 1:
                    in_quotes = not in_quotes
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                skip_next = False

        if in_quotes:
            return False
    return True

def check_and_parse_potential_tuple(to_parse):
    """
    receives a string and returns an array of the attributes of the csv line
    if the string was not a valid csv line, then returns False
    """
    a_tuple = []
    attribute_start_index = 0
    to_parse_len = len(to_parse)
    in_quotes = False
    i = 0

    #iterate through the string (line from the csv)
    while i < to_parse_len:
        current_char = to_parse[i]

        #this works the following way: if we meet a quote ("), it must be in one
        #of five cases: "" | ", | ," | "\0 | (start_of_string)"
        #in case we are inside a quoted attribute (i.e. "123"), then commas are ignored
        #the following code also extracts the tuples' attributes 

        if current_char == '\"':
            if i == 0 or (to_parse[i - 1] == ',' and not in_quotes): # (start_of_string)" and ," case
                #not including the quote in the next attr
                attribute_start_index = i + 1

                #starting a quoted attr
                in_quotes = True
            elif i + 1 < to_parse_len:
                if to_parse[i + 1] == '\"': # "" case
                    i += 1 #skip the next " because it is part of a ""
                elif to_parse[i + 1] == ',' and in_quotes: # ", case
                    a_tuple.append(to_parse[attribute_start_index:i].strip())

                    #not including the quote and comma in the next attr
                    attribute_start_index = i + 2

                    in_quotes = False #the quoted attr has ended

                    #skip the next comma - we know what it is for
                    i += 1
                else:
                    #since we cannot have a random " in the middle of an attr
                    return False 
            elif i == to_parse_len - 1: # "\0 case
                a_tuple.append(to_parse[attribute_start_index:i].strip())

                #reached end of line, so no more attr's to extract
                attribute_start_index = to_parse_len

                in_quotes = False
            else:
                return False
        elif current_char == ',':
            if not in_quotes:
                a_tuple.append(to_parse[attribute_start_index:i].strip())
                attribute_start_index = i + 1

        i += 1

    #in case the last attr was left empty or unquoted
    if attribute_start_index < to_parse_len or (not in_quotes and to_parse[-1] == ','):
        a_tuple.append(to_parse[attribute_start_index:])

    #line ended while parsing; i.e. a quote was openned but not closed 
    if in_quotes:
        return False

    return a_tuple


def parse_tuple(to_parse, no_of_headers):
    """
    parses a string and returns an array with no_of_headers number of headers

    raises an error if the string was not a valid CSV line
    """

    #get rid of the newline at the end of every line
    to_parse = to_parse.strip()

    # return to_parse.split(',') #if we assume the data is in a valid format

    #the following checking of the format of the data increases the execution
    #time by a factor of 2; if the data is know to be valid, uncomment 3 lines above here

    #if there are more commas than fields, then we must take into consideration
    #how the quotes parse and then extract the attributes
    if to_parse.count(',') + 1 > no_of_headers:
        result = check_and_parse_potential_tuple(to_parse)
        if result:
            a_tuple = result
        else:
            raise TypeError('Error while parsing CSV line %s. The quotes do not parse' % to_parse)
    else:
        a_tuple = to_parse.split(',')
        if not csv_tuple_quotes_valid(a_tuple):
            raise TypeError('Error while parsing CSV line %s. The quotes do not parse' % to_parse)

    #if the format is correct but more data fields were provided
    #the following works faster than an if statement that checks the length of a_tuple
    try:
        a_tuple[no_of_headers - 1]
    except IndexError:
        raise TypeError('Error while parsing CSV line %s. Unknown reason' % to_parse)

    #this replaces the use my own hashtables to store the duplicated values for the attributes
    for i in range(1, no_of_headers):
        a_tuple[i] = sys.intern(a_tuple[i])

    return a_tuple


def read_file(path, file_number):
    """
    reads the csv file and returns (dict, int)

    the dict is the mapping of id's to attributes

    the integer is the number of attributes (headers) for the csv file
    """
    global HEADERS

    try:
        file = open(path, 'r');
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print("error in %s:\n%s\nexiting...")
        exit(1)

    main_table = {}
    headers = file.readline().strip().split(',')
    no_of_headers = len(headers)

    HEADERS.extend(headers[1:]) #keep the headers from the file

    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    args = []
    for line in lines:
        args.append((line, no_of_headers))

    #pool is a pool of worker processes parsing the lines in parallel
    with Pool() as workers:
        try:
            all_tuples = workers.starmap(parse_tuple, args, 1000)
        except TypeError as e:
            print('Error in file %s:\n%s\nexiting thread...' % (path, e.args))
            exit(1)

    for a_tuple in all_tuples:
        #add quotes to key if needed
        key = a_tuple[0] if a_tuple[0][0] == '\"' else ('\"%s\"' % a_tuple[0])
        main_table[key] = a_tuple[1:]

    return (main_table, no_of_headers)

def merge_files():
    """
    produces a file called merged.csv 
    """
    global HEADERS

    no_of_files = len(sys.argv) - 1
    processed_files = [None] * no_of_files

    for i in range(0, no_of_files):
        processed_files[i] = read_file(sys.argv[i + 1], i)

    out_file = open('merged.csv', 'w+')

    merged_str = ','.join(HEADERS)

    all_keys = {}
    #this is to ensure that we include all keys in the final file.
    #even those that are missing from some files and present in others
    for processed_file in processed_files:
        all_keys.update(processed_file[0])

    for key in all_keys:
        merged_str += '\n%s' % key
        for i in range(0, no_of_files):
            (main_table, no_of_headers) = processed_files[i]

            try:
                for attr in main_table[key]:
                    merged_str += ',%s' % attr
            except KeyError:
                print('NOTE: no values found for id %s in file \"%s\"' % (key, sys.argv[i + 1]))
                merged_str += ',' * (no_of_headers - 1)

    out_file.write(merged_str)
    out_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # merge_files()
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run('merge_files()')

# import time
# start = time.time()

# print(time.time() - start);
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/vTkTJnDD) is the profiler report I got on my Windows.

EDIT: The rest of the csv data provided is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xMneDRen-a_mV1_ZAEpN1pU-jC4p0NjE/view?usp=sharing). Pastebin was taking too long to process the files, so...

It might not be the best code and I know that, but my question is what slows down Windows so much that doesn't slow down an Ubuntu? The merge_files() function takes the longest, with 94 seconds just for itself, not including the calls to other functions. And there doesn't seem to be anything too obvious to me for why it is so slow.

Thanks

EDIT: Note: We both used the same dataset to run the code with.

Comment: One possibility: `multiprocessing` works differently on Windows vs Linux. It may be a cause of the discrepancy here, but I wouldn't know enough to say more with confidence.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the csv files? I'm not sure if stackoverflow allows an external link like pastebin to upload the files but that might help to get a better idea of your code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this happened even before I used multiprocessing. I used it because they said it was too slow

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce https://pastebin.com/huWNvMtP this is part of one of the files

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Thanks for the sample as it helps to see the format but are the full files too big to upload all three somewhere? It's hard to get accurate results without all three.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Windows and Linux handle ***very*** long strings differently. When I moved the `out_file.write(merged_str)` inside the outer for loop (`for key in all_keys:`) and stopped appending to `merged_str`, it ran for 11 seconds as expected. I don't have enough knowledge on either of the OS's memory management systems to be able to give a prediction on why it is so different.

But I would say that the way that the second one (the Windows one) is the more fail-safe method because it is unreasonable to keep a 30 MB string in memory. It just turns out that Linux sees that and doesn't always try to keep the string in cache, or to rebuild it every time.

Funny enough, initially I did run it a few times on my Linux machine with these same writing strategies, and the one with the large string seemed to go faster, so I stuck with it. I guess you never know.

Here's the modified code

```
    for key in all_keys:
        merged_str = '%s' % key
        for i in range(0, no_of_files):
            (main_table, no_of_headers) = processed_files[i]

            try:
                for attr in main_table[key]:
                    merged_str += ',%s' % attr
            except KeyError:
                print('NOTE: no values found for id %s in file \"%s\"' % (key, sys.argv[i + 1]))
                merged_str += ',' * (no_of_headers - 1)
        out_file.write(merged_str + '\n')

    out_file.close()
```

Comment: I find strange to see this kind of behavior just due to the underlying memory management... 32 MB of data is definitely not that unusual - especially when dealing with images, if Windows were to swap it out all the time no image processing could be done efficiently. Is it possible instead that you are comparing a 64 bit Linux CPython with a 32 bit Windows CPython? Do the times stay the same if you use 64 bit Windows CPython?

Comment: Python strings are immutable which might explain the performance issue. Instead of adding the short string B to the existing big string A, a new string object C is created and contents of A and B are copied to it. Memory allocation for A and B will be probably deallocated at the same time. Allocating and deallocating something like 32 MB in a loop is likely to affect the performance.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala exactly, but why is it so fast on Linux?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I just tried it on a 64-bit python on a 64-bit windows 10, and the performance was the same

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov My guess is that the use of `mmap` by `malloc` could have some effect.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your solution on Ubuntu 16.04 with the three given files, it seems to take ~8 seconds to complete. The only modification I made was to uncomment the timing code at the bottom and use it.

```
$ python3 dimitar_merge.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
NOTE: no values found for id "aaa5d09b-684b-47d6-8829-3dbefd608b5e" in file "file2.csv"
NOTE: no values found for id "38f79a49-4357-4d5a-90a5-18052ef03882" in file "file2.csv"
NOTE: no values found for id "766590d9-4f5b-4745-885b-83894553394b" in file "file2.csv"
8.039648056030273
$ python3 dimitar_merge.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
NOTE: no values found for id "38f79a49-4357-4d5a-90a5-18052ef03882" in file "file2.csv"
NOTE: no values found for id "766590d9-4f5b-4745-885b-83894553394b" in file "file2.csv"
NOTE: no values found for id "aaa5d09b-684b-47d6-8829-3dbefd608b5e" in file "file2.csv"
7.78482985496521
```

I rewrote my first attempt without using `csv` from the standard library and am now getting times of ~4.3 seconds.

```
$ python3 lettuce_merge.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
4.332579612731934
$ python3 lettuce_merge.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
4.305467367172241
$ python3 lettuce_merge.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
4.27345871925354
```

This is my solution code (`lettuce_merge.py`):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def split_row(csv_row):
    return [col.strip('"') for col in csv_row.rstrip().split(',')]


def merge_csv_files(files):
    file_headers = []
    merged_headers = []
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        current_header = split_row(next(file))
        unique_key, *current_header = current_header
        if i == 0:
            merged_headers.append(unique_key)
        merged_headers.extend(current_header)
        file_headers.append(current_header)

    result = defaultdict(lambda: [''] * (len(merged_headers) - 1))
    for file_header, file in zip(file_headers, files):
        for line in file:
            key, *values = split_row(line)
            for col_name, col_value in zip(file_header, values):
                result[key][merged_headers.index(col_name) - 1] = col_value
        file.close()

    quotes = '"{}"'.format
    with open('lettuce_merged.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(','.join(quotes(a) for a in merged_headers) + '\n')
        for key, values in result.items():
            f.write(','.join(quotes(b) for b in [key] + values) + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType
    from time import time

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*', type=FileType('r'))
    args = parser.parse_args()

    start_time = time()
    merge_csv_files(args.files)
    print(time() - start_time)
```

I'm sure this code could be optimized even further but sometimes just seeing another way to solve a problem can help spark new ideas.

Comment: This is my first post and sorry for not providing the necessary info. I updated the post question right now to include the 3 csv's and the statement of the problem. They asked me to take care of the CSV parsing. It took me more time than the actual merging to sort out.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov No problem! Now that I have the question text and actual files, I will take another look. One last thing, are you positive that the output of your script is the exact format that they asked for? Did they confirm (even though it was slow) that it did indeed produce the correct output?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to investigate. They confirmed that my results were correct and that they get the same results with a model solution.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Perfect, I will take another look.